# CEFsharp load url is holding on to the previously navigated url

Tags: c++, cefsharp, chromium-embedded, embedded-browser

We have a C++ application (using Owl UI framework) which calls a CEFsharp Chromiumbrowser control inside an owl dialog. It is working perfectly the first time and the chromium embedded control shows the page properly. It is important to mention here that the first url which is say "http//www.someurl" navigates internally to "http://www.anotherurl/opensomething" each time. When we close the Owl MDI window and then try to open it again, the CEFSharp browser control tries to go straight to "http://www.anotherurl/opensomething" instead of going to "http//www.someurl" which it is being specifically asked to navigate to. We are using Chromiumbrowser load method to load the url but just cannot make it to load the first url from the second time onward. Our CEFsharp version is 63.03 . However if we open the chromium browser control in its own window and not embed it inside the MDI dialog it works perfectly everytime. Can't figure out so far as to why this is not loading the url properly from the second time around. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Does the problem reproduce with version `69.0.0`? Version `63.0.3` is old and no longer supported. `CefSharp` is built with `GitLink` so you can step into the code and add your own breakpoints, see https://github.com/GitTools/GitLink
This is likely an issue you'll have to debug yourself as it's unique to your environment and you've only described the issue, not provided a means of reproducing it. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If you are using `C++` you can skip using `CefSharp` and implement `CEF` directly, you'll have greater control of the browser (obviously comes with some cost).

Comment: @amaitland Thanks for the suggestions and help. Yes we tried with 69.0 also and had the same problem. We are using visual studio 2013 so we downgraded to 63.03 so as not have to supply the C++ 2015 redistributables.